# My session does not persist on other pages

Tags: php, session

I made a custom code to keep the section, I soon on a page and I'm returned to the same page, with session saved and returning login as success.

But at the time I'm going to save the information from a form on this page I check if I'm logged in and it's returned as I fail.

I also noticed that when I log in and go through the navigation menu to another page that checks the login, the session tbm does not keep.

Does anyone know what it can be, or do you find something that I am missing from these functions?

**Method to save form information after login**

```
  <? php
    include_once 'functions.php';

    sec_session_start ();

    $ error_msg = "";
    $ page = "postar.php";

    if (isset ($ _ POST [post]) && $ _POST [post] == ​​"Upload") {
      $ Image = "";

      if (isset ($ _ FILES [btcapa]) &&! empty ($ _ FILES [btcapa] [name])) {
        $ btimage = $ _FILES [btcapa];
        switch ($ _ POST [sacervo]) {
          case '1':
            $ update = "img / comic";
            break;
          case '2':
            $ update = "img / books";
            break;
          case '3':
            $ updir = "img / files";
            break;
        }
        $ Image = valida_upload ($ btimage, $ update);
        if ($ Image [0] == '<') {
        $ error_msg. = "<li> Document: not loaded." $ btimage [name]. "</ li>";
        $ error_msg. = $ Image;
        $ Image = '';
      }
    }

    if (login_check ($ mysqli) == true) {
      switch ($ _ POST [sacervo]) {
        case '1':
          $ error_msg. = valida_gibis ($ mysqli, $ Image);
          break;
        case '2':
          $ error_msg. = validate_book ($ mysqli, $ Image);
          break;
        case '3':
          $ error_msg. = validate_files ($ mysqli, $ Image);
          break;
      }
      if ($ error_msg == '') {
        if (! empty ($ Image)) {$ upload = move_uploaded_file ($ _ FILES [btcapa] [tmp_name], $ Image); }

        $ msg_sucesso = "<li> Successfully inserted. </ li>";
        header ('Location: ../'.$page.'?retorno='.$msg_sucesso);
      } else {
        header ('Location: ../'.$page.'?retorno='.$error_msg);
      }
    } else {
      $ error_msg. = "<li> Could not insert, please log back in. </ li>";
      header ('Location: ../postar.php?retorno='.$error_msg);
    }
    }
  ?>
```

**Personal logon feature**

```
function sec_session_start() {
        $session_name = 'SESSION';   // Estabeleça um nome personalizado para a sessão
        $secure = SECURE;
        // Isso impede que o JavaScript possa acessar a identificação da sessão.
        $httponly = true;
        // Assim você força a sessão a usar apenas cookies. 
       if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) == FALSE) {
            header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
            exit();
        }
        // Obtém params de cookies atualizados.
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
        session_set_cookie_params(time()+3600,
            $cookieParams[path], 
            $cookieParams[domain], 
            $secure,
            $httponly);
        // Estabelece o nome fornecido acima como o nome da sessão.
        session_name($session_name);
        ob_start();  
        session_start();            // Inicia a sessão PHP 
        session_regenerate_id();    // Recupera a sessão e deleta a anterior.

        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() + 3600, $params[path], $params[domain], $secure, $httponly);
}
```

**Function that checks if this is logged in**

```
function login_check($mysqli) {
    // Verifica se todas as variáveis das sessões foram definidas 
    if (isset($_SESSION[user_id], $_SESSION[username], $_SESSION[login_string])) {

        $user_id = $_SESSION[user_id];
        $login_string = $_SESSION[login_string];
        $username = $_SESSION[username];

        // Pega a string do usuário.
        //$user_browser = $_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT];

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT usuarioSenha FROM usuario WHERE usuarioCod = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            // Atribui "$user_id" ao parâmetro. 
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                // Caso o usuário exista, pega variáveis a partir do resultado.                 
                $stmt->bind_result($password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $login_check = $password;//hash('sha512', $password.$user_browser);

                if ($login_check == $login_string) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Login function**

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Usando definições pré-estabelecidas significa que a injeção de SQL (um tipo de ataque) não é possível. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT usuarioCod, usuarioNome, usuarioSenha
        FROM usuario
            WHERE usuarioEmail = ?
            LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Relaciona  "$nusp" ao parâmetro.
        $stmt->execute();    // Executa a tarefa estabelecida.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // obtém variáveis a partir dos resultados. 
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $user_name, $user_senha);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // faz o hash da senha com um salt excusivo.
        //$password = hash('sha512', $password);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

            if ($user_senha == $password) {
                $_SESSION[user_id] = $user_id;
                $_SESSION[username] = $user_name;
                $_SESSION[login_string] = $user_senha;//hash('sha512', $password.$user_browser);

                return '';
            }
        } else {
            // Tal usuário não existe.
            return '<p class="error"> Não existe esse usuario </p>';
        }
    }else {
        return '<p class="error"> contate o adiministrador </p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` on each page?

Comment: yes, on each page I make a 'sec_session_star()', the function that is there, it contains 'the session_start()'. If I try only 'session_start()' does not work nor can login.

Comment: in Personal logon feature you start a session twice, why is that?

Comment: Where am I starting twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed these 3 functions from `my session_start()` customized to `sec_session_start()` resoveu but I do not know why.

```
ob_start();  
session_regenerate_id();
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() + 3600, $params[path], $params[domain], $secure, $httponly);
```